# VOLATILE required in single core multi Threaded environment?

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

Do I need to use VOLATILE variable, if I am on a single core machine & multi Threaded environment

From my understanding, Threads do not have a cache space of their own.

They use the cache of the core they are running in.

Now if it is a single core machine, they will all be sharing the same cache.

Please correct/addMore over my understanding

Comment: You need volatile. Nowhere it is said that Threads do not have a cache of their own (they have - in the form of e.g. JIT compiled code). In short: You can not guarantee your program will behave correct and has no data races just because it runs on a single core.

Comment: And even if it was possible to skip volatile because of a single core architecture, you shouldn't. You'll never know what machine your code might need to run on.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler can also reorder instructions.

For example:

```
class SomeRunnable implements Runnable{
  public boolean stop;

  public void run(){
     while(!stop)
         println("hello");
  }
}
```

Since the stop variable isn't marked as volatile (or used in a synchronized block), the compiler is free to transform the above code to:

```
class SomeRunnable implements Runnable{
  public boolean stop;

  public void run(){
     if(stop)return;
     for(;;)
         println("hello");
  }
}
```

This optimization is called 'loop invariant code motion'. The reason this optimization is done is to reduce the overhead of reading 'stop'; what is the point of reading it, if it doesn't change in the loop.

It is best not to think in terms of caches because:

- unless you know what you are talking about, probably you don't understand it correctly
- it depends on the CPU architecture.

If you want to understand Java concurrent, then you need to understand the Java Memory Model.